# getContextByIndex doesn't return all the columns

Tags: sapui5, binding-context

I have following code

```
oTableEntry = this.getView().byId("oTable");
var count = oTableEntry._getRowCount();
var oTData;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    oTData = oTableEntry.getContextByIndex(i).getObject();
```

`oTData` doesn't contain values for all the columns even though they appear in the table. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: To get the values of each roll cell for some calculations by using the variable oTData.

Comment: check my answer below. Let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: I think you need all the table columns and the corresponding rows bind data.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to get the table columns and their values for each row. Here is how you can do this:

```js
var oTable = this.getView().byId("oTable");//Get the table by Id    
var aItems = oTable.getAggregation("items");//get the items of the table
for (var i=0; i<aItems.length; i++) {
  var tableColumns = aItems[i].getAggregation("cells");     //Here tableColumns will    //have all the columns of the table rows. 
  var column1Value = tableColumns[1].getProperty("text");
}
```

Comment: I had the following issue when I use the similar code earlier.  https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/393

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are looking for same solution!!

```
var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("YourTableID");
if (oTable) {
 var oColumns = oTable.getColumns();//get all columnms
 var oRows = oTable.getItems();
 for (var r in  oRows) {
    var oRow = oRows[r];
    console.log(oRow.getBindingContext().getObject());//return the row data
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Doesn't work either. Get the same issue as https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/393 :(

Comment: `oTable.getItems()` return only the visible rows, if you want all the rows(items) then you need to get the bind data from the model itself. I will update the code